# Posted data length issue when posted through $.ajax and server is IIS

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iis

I am posting the data using $.ajax and server side is php file where i have to get content.If the data posted is of less length it posted successfully but if length is too much it doesnot .The same code is working fine on another server(server 1) but its not working server 2.I have seen the settings of IIS  of requestLimits 
maxAllowedContentLength is 300000000
maxQueryString is 4096
maxUrl is 4096

in php.ini also postmaxsize is 50M  .Posted data is hardly 5 MB .
Still is dont see any posted data in my php file  when i print the posted data .

Comment: Does server1 and server2 both have same php configuration or different

Comment: Both having same php.ini settings @Haridarshan